# Unity Time Checker

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a time checker that can be implemented in unity? For example I want to check todays date and time, could I call something from google or another source to check time that way I don't check user device time which they could change. Any links or info would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I used. It uses UnityWebRequest (It requires Unity 5.2.0 or higher) for https and https://nist.time.gov/actualtime.cgi for the time, Uses coroutine to wait for the response

nist.time.gov/actualtime.cgi response :

```
// time * 10 == ticks
<timestamp time="1538381371720144" delay="0"/>
```

code :

```
public DateTime LastSyncedLocalTime
{
    get;
    private set;
}

public DateTime LastSyncedServerTime
{
    get;
    private set;
}

public DateTime InterpolatedUtcNow
{
    get
    {
        return DateTime.UtcNow + (LastSyncedServerTime - LastSyncedLocalTime);
    }
}

public IEnumerator Sync()
{
    using (var www = UnityWebRequest.Get("https://nist.time.gov/actualtime.cgi"))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.LogError(www.error);
            yield break;
        }

        var timestamp = XElement.Parse(www.downloadHandler.text);
        var ticks = long.Parse(timestamp.Attribute(XName.Get("time")).Value) * 10;

        LastSyncedLocalTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        LastSyncedServerTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddTicks(ticks);
    }
}
```

Comment: Question: The code seems incomplete or I dont understand it that well, just so I can understand it. How could you set Ui-text to show the Date, time etc?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know Unity does not support any way of getting the time that cannot be changed on the local device. I think your best solution to get around this would be to run a small php script to get the time using the [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) format.

`<?php echo "Today is " . date("Y/m/d");>` which will return the local time

You can then retrieve this data using the [WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) class

```
public static IEnumerator GetTimeStamp(string url, RequestCompletedCallback callback)
{
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);//url would be where the php script is hosted
    www.SendWebRequest();

    while (!www.isDone)
    {
        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Web request failed: ", www.error);
        }
        yield return null;
    }
    // Store results in a string
    if (callback != null)
    {
        string result = www.downloadHandler.text;
    }

    www.Dispose();
}
```

Another solution would be using an API that returns dates like [timezonedb](https://timezonedb.com/) or [timeanddate](https://www.timeanddate.com/services/api/)